# Term for labelled graph in which vertices and edges are partitioned into disjoint subsets

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Suppose there exists a graph $G = (V, E)$ and some finite index set $\mathcal{S} = \{1, \ldots, S\}$ in which

- $V \equiv \cup_{s \in \mathcal{S}} V_{s}$ where $\{V_{s} \subseteq V \mid V_{r} \cap V_{s} = \varnothing \text{ for each } r\neq s \in \mathcal{S}\}$ exactly covers $V$
- $E \equiv \cup_{r,s \in S} E_{rs}$ where $\{E_{rs} \subseteq V_{r} \times V_{s} \mid E_{pq} \cap E_{rs} = \varnothing \text{ for each } p\neq r, q\neq s \in \mathcal{S}\}$ exactly covers $E$.  Furthermore, $(i, j) \in E_{rs} \Rightarrow i \in V_{r} \text{ and } j \in V_{s}$

In other words, a graph with vertices are partitioned into $S$ distinct types and the edges are partitioned into $S^2$ distinct types.  Edges can exist both within (i.e. $E_{ss}$) and between (i.e. $E_{rs}$) each distinct vertex type.

Is there an existing term in the literature of this special case of labelling?  I am aware that this object is both an edge-labeled and vertex-labeled graph and that this is not a case of graph coloring.  If I understand correctly, this is also not a multipartite graph, since there can exist an edge between vertices of the same label or color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is precisely an $|\mathcal{S}|$-partite graph where the parts are $V_r$; $r \in \mathcal{S}$ [no edges between vertices in the same $V_r$ for each $r \in \mathcal{S}$]. IF there is an edge between *every* $i \in V_r$ and $j \in V_s$ for all distinct $r,s$ then it is a *complete* $|\mathcal{S}|$-partite graph where the parts are $V_r$; $r \in \mathcal{S}$.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I added some edits for clarity and to be more precise.  What if there do exist edges between vertices in the same $V_{r}$?

Comment: Then it is just a graph  on $\cup_r V_r$ then

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Given the comment above, I will accept this answer.